# How to remove links from tags in html?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm writing scraper in Python with bs4 and want to remove links from all 'a' tags

I have html code

```
html_code = '<a href="link">some text</a>'
```

I want to remove href="link" and get only

```
html_code = '<a>some text</a>'
```

How can i do it?

Comment: You can also use https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html

Comment: The `<a>` tag without the `href` attribute is unliquidated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it following way

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_code = '<a href="link">some text</a>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_code)
print("Before")
print(soup.prettify())
for node in soup.find_all("a"):
    node.attrs = {}
print("After")
print(soup.prettify())
```

gives output

```
Before
<html>
 <body>
  <a href="link">
   some text
  </a>
 </body>
</html>
After
<html>
 <body>
  <a>
   some text
  </a>
 </body>
</html>
```

Note that this will remove all attributes of all `<a>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem?

```
html_code = html_code.replace(' href="link"','')
```

**Output:**

```
>>> print(html_code)

>>> '<a>some text</a>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('<a href="link">some text</a>', "html.parser")

del soup.a.attrs
print(soup.a)
```

Prints:

```html
<a>some text</a>
```